# How to implement Ctrl + Click

Tags: java, swing

How to check whether mouse clicked while holding other key on keyboard.
e.g

```
class mouseActions extends MouseInputAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e && KeyEvent e1) {
            //something
        }
```

Or

```
registerKeyboardAction(e -> {
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(MouseEvent.MouseClicked(), KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
```

I know this is crazy code but I can't find relevant syntax for that

Comment: could you just have two methods, one with the KeyEvent, one with the MouseEvent, and just update some variable like `isControlPressed` every time your KeyEvent method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all class names should start with an upper case character. Learn by example. All the classes in the JDK follow this standard.

The `MouseEvent` contains the information about any of the meta keys that may be pressed:

```
class MouseAction extends MouseInputAdapter 
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e ) 
    {
        if (e.isControlDown()
            // do something
    }
}
```